# How to append a file's line to a different file's line based on a commonality?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to take lines from a file and append it to the end of lines in another file, IF they have a commonality (the same path, in my case).

Example lines from the first file ('out.txt'):

```
\vol\vol1\path1: The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (119)
\vol\path2: Access is denied. (2)
\vol\vol24\path27: Access is denied. (401) Could not convert the name of inner file or directory (111)
```

Example lines from the file I'd like to append to ('fixed_inv.txt') in the form of a new file called 'concat.txt':

```
42  sggisnap013.example.com xskld_$FOLw \vol\vol1\path1
42  sggisnap013.example.com /vol/vol7   /vol/vol7   
42  sggisnap013.example.com HOME    \vol\vol0\home
```

As you can see in both files, there is a commonality. It happens to be the path: `\vol\vol1\path1`

Sometimes you'll see the same paths with a different server name (sggisnap013.example.com) like:

```
44  tkgisnstor012.nomura.com    /vol/vol1
42  sggisnap013.example.com xskld_$FOLw /vol/vol1
```

It must have the same server AND path before executing the append.

However, in other cases, the commonality will be a different path.

I've written this code:

```
err = []
inv = []

with open('out.txt', 'r') as f1:
 for line in f1: #for each line
    split_line = line.split(' ') 
    index_f1 = split_line[0] 
    err = index_f1    

with open('fixed_inv.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for line in f2: #for each line
        split_line = line.split('\t') #split the line by each tab, call that split_line
        index_f2 = split_line[3] #key2 will hold the item occuring at split index 3
        inv.append(index_f2)

with open('concat.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in err:
        for line in inv:
            if err == inv:
                file_out.write(line)
            else:
                continue
```

> ***NOTE:*** `'out.txt'` is the file I'm appending to `'fixed_inv.txt'`. The result will be a new file.

However, when I run this, I get something interesting, but not what I want:

```
\\\\\\\\aappppsssss__33\\\\ttrrssssspprrsssss
```

I would appreciate any ideas for how to go about doing this properly. Thank you.

Comment: Not entirely understand your question. So, you want to check if the files have common path and append their lines to newly created file, is that it ?

Comment: So IF the path of a line in the 'out.txt' file can be found in the 'fixed_inv.txt' file, then we want to append that line of 'out.txt' to the end of the line in 'fixed_inv.txt' containing the path match. Let me know if that helps, Anthony!

Comment: Is this `42  sggisnap013.example.com xskld_$FOLw \vol\vol1\path1` the format for entire files. I mean, file path is alway at the end of the line and separated with whitespace ?

Comment: It is not always at the end of the line, there's usually a bunch of items after separated by a tab or space. The path should be in the third index if you split the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('concat.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line_e in err:
        for line_i in inv:
        if line_e == line_i:
            file_out.write(line_i)
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Tried this but still nothing is printing to concat.txt which is weird since there's data in both of the files I'm opening and there should be at least one match...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look, it might give you some idea:

```
def common(file1, file2, file3):
''' 
    file1 - name for the source file (out.txt)
    file2 - name for second source file (fixed_inv.txt)
    file3 - name for output file (concat.txt)
'''

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
  with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
      with open(file3, 'a') as f3:
         for l1,l2 in zip(f1,f2):
             path1 = l1[:l1.index(':')]
             paths_list = [x.strip() for x in l2.split(' ') \
                  if x.startswith("\\") or x.startswith("/")]
             for line in paths_list:
                 #if line.find('\\\\') != -1:
                     #line = line.replace("\\\\", '\\' )
                 if line == path1:
                     f3.write(path1)
```

We have 3 params `file1, file2, file3` that are your source files and an output one. We open them all at the same time and start processing data.

```
path1 = l1[:l1.index(':')]
```

This line stores a path from `out.txt`. For instance, if your first line is

```
`\vol\vol1\path1: The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (119)`
```

then path1 is

```
`path1="\vol\vol1\path1"`
```

Then we get all the paths from each line in  `fixed_inv.txt`. For instance, if your the line is

```
42  sggisnap013.example.com /vol/vol7   /vol/vol7
```

then list will be:

```
paths_list=['/vol/vol7', '/vol/vol7']
```

And the last par will be, as far as I understood, like this:

```
for line in paths_list:
  if line == path1: # replace with your condition 
    f3.write(path1)
```

Here we compare path from the `out.txt` with all possible paths from `ixed_inv.txt` and if `#your condition is True`, than we write to output file `concat.txt`

---

By the way, with this check

```
`#if line.find('\\\\') != -1:
    #line = line.replace("\\\\", '\\' )`
```

you can replace `'\\vol\\vol1\\path1'` path with `'\vol\vol1\path1'`, if there would be any need for that.